# Xamarin/Azure Notification Hubs GCM registration removed after sending

Tags: xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have a Xamarin Android app setup using the [GCMClient](https://github.com/Redth/GCM.Client) library as recommended in the [Azure tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm). When sending a notification from code or a test notification through the Azure portal (or the Azure VS plugin) the device registration is removed and the following response is received from Azure Notification Hubs:

> The Push Notification System handle for the registration is no longer valid

I have commented out all code in the app that unsubscribes the registration, tried running on an emulator with the Google API's & a physical Nexus device in both debug & release mode but still the registration is removed whenever a notification is sent.

I have also configured an existing web app to use the same Azure Notification Hub; the web app uses Chrome's web push notifications with a service worker and it works perfectly, the registration is never removed from Notification Hubs and the test messages come through every time.

*I have verified the usual's; Sender ID & Azure NH connection string are both correct...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

1. Can you check if the credentials you have set for GCM are correct.
   Use this link:
   [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-  hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer#self-diagnose-tips)
2. Make sure you register with the latest device token whenever the App opens up to make sure the registrations are up to date.

I am assuming the registrations exists before you send the notification. But just to make sure, please check your registration Id using Visual studio server explorer
See link [Verify Registrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer#self-diagnose-tips)

Comment: My bad for the first link use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm

Comment: Ahh I didn't realise the registration had to be updated every time the device opens, that would explain the sporadic nature of the missing registrations. I had hoped to only register devices that opt into registrations but I guess I will just register everyone on startup.

Comment: Hmmm, you should only register customers who have opt into push. And even though we recommend re-registering on app start-up, GCM's token doesn't change very often, so there shouldn't be missing devices everywhere. You might want to check on the tokens to make sure their alterations are what is causing the issue.

Comment: I am also running into this and can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. @Anth12 did you figure it out? I am registering on startup and it shows up in the registrations, but as soon as I send the test it goes away and gives me the same error.

Comment: @JamesMontemagno The issue I had was that in addition to not re-registering the device token I was caching the originally issued value thinking it would still be valid so essentially I was attempting to re-register an invalid token. I had the same issue on iOS too. Which platform are you having trouble with?